# AWS Serverless framework use GIT for collaboration

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I have created a sample project on my laptop using [serverless AWS framework](http://serverless.com/),

```
$ serverless project install serverless-starter
```

Working fine.

Now, I pushed the project to my GIT account.

Then I pulled that project on another computer...

So how can I "Install" the project on the new computer?, Is this the way to manage collaboration with GIT? what is preferred?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to `init` after cloning it from your Git.

```
serverless project init
```

Reference: http://docs.serverless.com/docs/project-init